# Calling a variable from one function in another function vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to call the `ctx` variable from the initGrid() function and use it in the drawGrid() function, however it doesn't let me use the variable even if i use "this."

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    squareH: 15,
    squareW: 15,
    squareRow: 10,
    squareCol: 10,
    squares: [],  
  }),
  
  directives: {},
  methods: {
    initGrid() {
      let grid = document.getElementById('grid');
      
      var ctx = grid.getContext('2d');
      
    },
    drawGrid() {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      this.ctx.fillRect(10, 10, this.squareW, this.squareH); 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initGrid();
    this.drawGrid();
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to your data object and use it in both methods :

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    squareH: 15,
    squareW: 15,
    squareRow: 10,
    squareCol: 10,
    squares: [],  
  ctx:null
  }),

  directives: {},
  methods: {
    initGrid() {
      let grid = document.getElementById('grid');

     this.ctx = grid.getContext('2d');

    },
    drawGrid() {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      this.ctx.fillRect(10, 10, this.squareW, this.squareH); 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initGrid();
    this.drawGrid();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the component access to the data. When you do `var ctx = grid.getContext('2d');` in init grid, the grid and ctx are created there, but you're not telling vue, or this component that it should "own" or associate the state with it. 
You can fix this by actually initializing the component's data with the ctx information.

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    squareH: 15,
    squareW: 15,
    squareRow: 10,
    squareCol: 10,
    squares: [],
    ctx: null, 
    // Note how we add ctx to the data here.  
  }),
  
  directives: {},
  methods: {
    initGrid() {
      let grid = document.getElementById('grid');
      
      // Now this.ctx is defined and can be used
       this.ctx = grid.getContext('2d');
      
    },
    drawGrid() {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      this.ctx.fillRect(10, 10, this.squareW, this.squareH); 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initGrid();
    this.drawGrid();
    
  }
```